# Kubernetes: not able to access outside service from my kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, service, kubernetes-pod, gateway, express-gateway

I have a gateway running as a pod and accessing it via NodePort service on port 3XXXX on a server.
I am able to send traffic to this gateway.
But I am not able to forward traffic from this gateway pod to a service that is on a different and server(this service is not a Kubernetes service).

It is showing timeout.
I am also not able to ping it from indside of pod.

I have whitelisted both servers with each other.
Please help me.

Comment: Can you provide your Express Gateway configuration?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod Thanks for your response Sir.
But can you be please more specific in config file because its my organisation file and not permited to provide much details.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal examples which shows the problem or we can’t help you.